# AutoLayout constraint animation not working after UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: ios, animation, keyboard, autolayout

For some reason I don't understand, my constraint animation does not work if I start it after a UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.  I'm modifying a "Bottom Space" constraint, to affect the  view's height.  What I expect is the views position relative to the view on top to stay the same and expand downwards.  However, the view's height instantly changes to the correct final height and moves upward.  THEN animates down to where it should have been in the first place, even though I never change the "Top Space" constraint.

If I animate the view before the UIKeyboardWillShow animation it works as I expect it, but I need the keyboard's height.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)nsNotification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [nsNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _editingBoxContraint.constant = kbSize.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Here are some images:

[image]

At beginning of animation.

[image]

At end of animation

Comment: I don't see the is when I try it. What constraints do you have on your editing box?

Comment: I have four constraints: Top Space to a button above it (which doesn't move during the animation) of 0, the bottom space constraint, and trailing and leading space to superview of 0.

Comment: Hmmm... I've modified mine to have those constraints, and it works fine. The constraint I'm modifying is on a UITextView. I assume keyboardWillShow is being called from a UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

Comment: You are correct on both the UITextView and the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your setup or constraints. If you could post your app somewhere, I could take a look at it, but otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Another interesting fact is that it works fine the first time, but not any other time afterwards.